# React Js- Can't see prop value inside html tag as key

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, key

Him I have a component, for some reason, I can't see any variable value inside the containing `<tr>` HTML tag.
between the `<td>` tag I can see the variable value.

If I write `<tr id={id}>` i receive the data but If I write `<tr key={id}>` I get only `<tr>` in the code.

The id is generated by `uuid` an dis something like this `62b82703-12f5-4fe6-903c-b875aa69246a`

What can be the reason for that?

**this is my component:**

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

class Course extends Component {
  updatedGrade = e => {
    this.props.updateCourseGrade(
      Number(e.currentTarget.value),
      Number(e.target.id)
    );
  };
  render() {
    const { id, courseName, courseGrade, courseType } = this.props.course;
    return (
      <tr key={id}>
        <td>
          {courseType == 0 ? "מכינה" : "אקדמי"} - {courseName} - {id}
        </td>
        <td>{courseGrade}</td>
        <td>
          <Button
            onClick={this.props.removeCourse.bind(this, id)}

            variant="danger"
          >
            הסר
          </Button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

const btnStyle = {
  background: "#ff0000",
  color: "#fff",
  padding: "5px 20 px",
  border: "0px"
};

export default Course;
```

Comment: Please check react's documentation for how 'keys' work. They are solely for the purpose of reconciliation. You cannot pass them down as props. https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys

Answer (score 6):

Keys in React are used to give React a hint to identify unique values in a list. But they aren't passed down to the component as a prop nor are added to the DOM after render.
If you want to actually see the Key in the DOM you need to specify it using a different prop.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using google chrome developer tool inspection? `key` won't be appeared on the devtool. Consider using reactJS devtool (you can download it via chrome extension store) to check the react component on the devtool, you cannot check react component directly via default developer tool.

`key` is not a valid html attribute, it's react specific, that's why you can't see that via chrome developer tool inspection.

Comment: o.k I see the key in the react dev tool
https://www.screencast.com/t/PlHbkNWkN0c

Will I always see the error in chrome console?

Comment: can you specify what error you encountered? @DavSev

Comment: This is the error `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. See https ://fb.me /react- warning-keys for more information.`

here is a screenshot of the complete error

Comment: here is a screenshot of the complete error https://www.screencast.com/t/Put2WI4QoSf

Comment: you should add ```key``` props to ```Course``` component since that component is the one being looped, am I right? @DavSev. i.e ```<Course key={UNIQUEKEY} />```

Comment: yes, you are right. so the key should be in the parent component?

Answer (score 0):

Add both the `key` and `id`:

```
<tr key={id} id={id}>...</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks, Not showing the `key` prop this is what I get `<tr id="8eff9d2e-23f2-4430-a89d-fdc2dd4f846e">` this is the code  `<tr key={id} id={id}>`